# Which Heroku plan would support many concurrent connections?

Tags: heroku, hosting

I have tried looking at Heroku's documentation but I couldn't find how many concurrent connections a plan can handle. Does it have anything to do with the number of dynos?

Eg.

In case I needed 500 connections and a dyno could handle only 100 of them, should I get many dynos or find a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of concurrent "connections" you can achieve depends on your app. If you're doing CPU, or memory intensive actions on each request, you will be able to handle much less concurrent connections than if you have a static site.

Heroku communicates the CPU share and memory available on every dyno type here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types

If you can't handle the number of connections you require, increasing the dyno size, their count or optimizing your app would indeed be the way to go.